# past simple and past continuous

Tags: grammar, tenses

Which of these verb forms is correct in each case?

1. I ***hoped/was hoping*** to go away this weekend, but my boss ***give/was giving me*** some work that I have to finish by Monday.
2. I bumped into Lena last week.She ***looked/was looking***a lot better than when I last spoke to her.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use the continuous tense with *give*, but it needs to be in the past tense - *my boss gave* or *has given me some work.*

You could say either *I was hoping* or *I had hoped* (the hope existed *before* you were given the work).

In (2), either the past tense or past continuous would be acceptable.